# Sign copyright agreement before paper acceptance?

Tags: paper-submission, copyright

I am submitting a research paper to a journal and they asked me to sign the copyright agreement in favour of the editor before the paper is accepted.  Is this right?
And what happens in this case is if the paper rejected?

Comment: What do you mean with “in favour of the editor”?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I think the OP talks about the possibility that the paper is rejected and later in the process - published (modified) by someone else. Without giving credit to the authors that did most of the work.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I doubt that. The author writes, that he was “asked to sign […] in favour of the editor“. The journal will hardly tell he should sign so that they can steal his work.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I agree on that part. I think **stealing** is too strong. Say the paper contains some huge mistakes, but has some promising idea's it's always hard to tell who *"came there first"*...

Answer (score 20):

This is rather normal for **non open-access articles** in my field (Physics), however all journals I have submitted to until now had a clause that the copyright transfer is voided if the paper is not accepted or withdrawn. For example IOP’s copyright agreement contains the following sentence:

> In the event that the Article is withdrawn prior to acceptance, or is rejected, this agreement shall have no effect and no party shall be bound by it.

If such conditions are included, requesting such an agreement at an early stage seems somewhat reasonable to me, since it would be a waste of time to review your paper if you did not agree with these terms.

If such conditions are not included, this is a clear warning sign that the publisher may be up to nothing good. However, even with such a clause, problems may arise, as the publisher may just instantly accept your article.

For **open-access articles** (pay-to-publish), a similar situation holds, however, the copyright agreement usally requires less commitment from you, as you should retain most rights on your article (since the journal does not make money with being the only one making your article available). This not applying to the copyright agreement is another warning sign of a predatory publisher.

**In both cases**, you should read the copyright agreement carefully and ensure the reputability of the publisher.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, a number of large-scale publishers expect you to sign over the copyrights before the article is accepted. For instance, the [American Chemical Society](http://pubs.acs.org), as well as the [Materials Research Society](http://www.mrs.org) will continually hound you about the transfer agreement until it's submitted, and moreover will not formally accept the article until they have the transfer agreement.

Comment: And so if they reject the paper, they hold the copyright and the author violates copyright by submitting the paper elsewhere?  This doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: No, usually the agreement is worded so that it's conditional on the manuscript being accepted.

Comment: I am looking at the MRS copyright form right now thanks to the link you provided, and I don't see any wording that makes it conditional on acceptance.  Did I miss it?

Comment: Hmm. The ACS version has it. Not sure why the MRS doesn't. But yeah, that could make things awkward. But I know when I had to submit proceedings there recently, all authors had to send in the transfer agreement at the time of submission.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The copyright form for the Journal of Materials Research begins with the clause "In consideration of the publication in Journal of Materials Research of the contribution entitled ..."  My non-expert opinion is that, if they do not publish the contribution, then there has been no consideration, therefore no contract, and therefore no transfer of the copyright.  (Legal experts are invited to correct my opinion.)

Comment: @Andreas: I don't read the wording that way.  For instance, the phrase you quote is not part of a complete sentence, so is not asserting anything, as far as I can see.  Also, by signing this form you are transferring over the copyright unconditionally, as far as I can see.  It is pretty well established that you don't need to publish what you have under copyright.  I would certainly not sign this form without at least checking how the journal interprets the language.

Comment: But the whole idea of signing over copyright before the paper is refereed or accepted just seems incoherent to me.  Presumably the submitted version of the paper is not identical to the published version.  If there are revisions (which is most often the case) it may actually be intellectually different.  Can you have one copyright form that covers different documents?  If so, I guess the journal has the right to make whatever revisions they want -- they have the copyright.  That sounds like an absolute mess.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I conjecture that the phrase about "In consideration" is part of a complete sentence, which is interrupted by a boldface section heading and instructions, and which then continues with "I/we assign ... online version." So I'm inclined to think that the copyright assignment is in the scope of the "In consideration" phrase and becomes void if there is no consideration. I'm also inclined to think that "the said contribution" refers to what is published, not what is submitted, since the published version is "said" in the earlier phrase.

Comment: Nevertheless, I agree that, before signing such a thing, one should find out what the publisher thinks it means. Perhaps even more relevant is what lawyers and judges think it means.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I agree that copyright transfer should be after/subject to acceptance and should be void if withdrawn by the author(s). But I'm not sure if it's the copyright that protects you from the publisher's evil modification such as publishing a paper under your name with contents you've never written or agreed with. Sure, it's unethical (and illegal in a serious case) to put words into your mouth, or to trick people into believing it's your work when it's not. But if your name is used this way without your consent, it seems to me it's more than just a copyright problem.

Comment: Besides, the publisher could do the same thing regardless of when you transfer copyright; your paper gets accepted and edited, so you give them the copyright. A few days later, you take a look at the latest issue, and lo and behold, the published version doesn't look anything like what you've written! I'm no lawyer, but I want to believe that there has to be a law that protects you from this kind of behavior other than copyright... I mean, if your name is abused this way, and if copyright is the only weapon to fight back, it's the publisher who has that precious weapon when you fight back...

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked this journal against Beall's list of [Preadatory Publishers](http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/) and [Preadatory Journals](http://scholarlyoa.com/individual-journals/)? There's little reason to sign over the copyright until the article is accepted, and this practice seems sketchy at best to me.

Comment: See my comment to @paulgarrett and the answer by aeismail: unfortunately, many large legitimate publishers do this, particularly in biomedical and chemistry journals.

Answer (score 3):

Many big publishers will often start asking pretty much immediately (I don't know if this is policy or just brain-dead software configuration). You can generally safely ignore these requests until the article is actually accepted, however, because until then the idea of copyright transfer is moot.  That is certainly the policy that I follow, and it hasn't caused me any trouble yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do not sign any copyright release before the paper is accepted, in any case.

The irregularity of this practice is itself a bad sign about the legitimacy of the journal.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of legitimate large publishers do this. For example, I have found ACS particularly obnoxious.

Comment: @jakebeal, I am amazed that this is still so. "We", collectively, should not tolerate it. Legit mathematics journals do not seem to do this, happily, despite their other manifold failings.

Comment: Unfortunately it is so: from what I have seen, math and physics generally have the most progressive publication policies, followed by computer science.  On the other end of the spectrum, many biomedical and chemistry publications are practically abusive, and this will not change until the authors in those communities object.